# How to subset data frame with actionButton based on user info on shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am loooking to run a chunk of code than performs a subset based on inputs chosen on the shiny UI.

To perform this, I have tried different approaches but with no luck:

I want to do something like this in the UI:

```
ui = navbarPage(title = 'panel',
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                column(2,
                       selectInput('a', label = "choose",
                                   choices = unique(df$a)),
                       sliderInput(
                         'b', label = 'choose range:',
                         min = 5, max = 8, value = c(6,7)),
                       actionButton('click','click')),
column(5,
      tableOutput('table')))))
```

and something like this on server

```
server = function(input,output){
                  df= data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(5,6,7,8))

  observeEvent(input$click,{
               df_ =  subset(df,  
               a == input$a & 
               b %in% input$b[1]:input$b[2])
               }) 

  input$table = renderDataTable({
  df_
  })
  }
```

Running this code takes me to this erros:

```
 shinyApp(ui, server)

 Warning: Error in $<-.reactivevalues: Attempted to assign value to a read-
 only reactivevalues object
 Stack trace (innermost first):
 47: $<-.reactivevalues
 46: $<- [#11]
 45: server [#11]
 4: <Anonymous>
 3: do.call
 2: print.shiny.appobj
 1: <Promise>
 Error in `$<-.reactivevalues`(`*tmp*`, "table", value = structure(function 
 (...)  : 
 Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object
```

I think Im missing some importante things with reactive values but I am lost, as I am new tho shiny. I have try some examples for reactive buttons such as the ones provided by Rstudio but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps we need to change the `input$table` to `output$table`, and use `DT::dataTableOutput('table')`in the 'ui'

```
library(shiny)
library(DT
fsel <- function(dat) {

ui = navbarPage(title = 'panel',
                fluidPage(
                  fluidRow(
                    column(2,
                           selectInput('a', label = "choose",
                                       choices = unique(dat$a), selected = unique(dat$a)[1]),
                           sliderInput(
                             'b', label = 'choose range:',
                             min = 5, max = 8, value = c(6,7)),
                           actionButton('click','click')),
                    column(5,
                           DT::dataTableOutput('table')))))


server = function(input,output){


  rs <- reactiveValues()


  rs$df <- dat
  observeEvent(input$click,{
  df_ <-  subset(dat,  
                  a == input$a & 
                    b %in% input$b[1]:input$b[2])
  rs$df <- df_
  }) 

  output$table = renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(rs$df)

  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) 
}
```

-data

```
df <- data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE), 
               b =1:10, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

-run the app

```
fsel(df)
```

-output
[image]

[image]